# Search Data by voice recognition instead of typing in text box

Tags: java, voice

Hi I have an application build on java where i can search book detail by entering its code in text box. Now i want perform same operation with voice recognition instead of typing. 
I have spend a lot of time on google i found many API like free ts Sphinx 4 etc. But didn't find any suitable example. Can any one suggest me latest API or provide me link having example. 
Currently i am doing search by entering code of book in text box and i get book detail. e.g
201 gives me xyz book.

Instead of typing i will say "201" and it will provide me book detail. I want to fill text box by voice.

Comment: do you want it to work offline or may it also be an online api? I have done a fair amount of tinkering around with different voice recognition apis in the past and the offline versions are non trivial to set up

Comment: i want to work offline. As the application is running locally.

Comment: offline usage without jni bindings leaves you with pretty much pocketsphinx or sphinx as your "viable" options. But as I said before, setting up grammar files AND receiving good recognition is another adventure. If you just have a limited set of words available this will work, for everything else one of the cloud based approaches like google amazon or microsoft azure are your way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voice recognition is itself a big industry, someone can speak in native language, others can say two zero one or two hundred one and many other combinations.Again its an application - web based / mobile based / desktop based the API features will be according.

Comment: i need only English language... Instead of number i have name field as well. I can use Name for search instead of number. My requirement is to fill text box by voice instead of typing.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java
There are various combinations you can try anyone